# Why is the pooled variance calculated using the variation of the two tested groups?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, variance, t-test

When comparing between two populations, or two groups from the same population, a t-test assumes that both those groups have the same variance. However, a t-test works by using the pooled variance calculation, which is calculated by:

$$s^2_p= \frac{(n_1-1)s_1^2 +(n_2-1)s_2^2 }{n_1+n_2-2};$$

$s_1$ and $s_2$ should be the same, so why is it presented this way?

Answer (score 0):

Population variances are assumed to be equal viz. $\sigma^2_1=\sigma^2_2=\sigma^2~(\textrm{say}). $ But this never implies $s^2_1=s^2_2.$

Comment: Still don't fully get it.. so $\sigma^2$ is the variance of the populations, and $s^2_1$, 
and $s^2_2$ are the variances of the samples from these populations? so we say that the populations variances equal and not the samples?

Comment: @ProgrammingNoob yes.